# Run wget command on each line of a file and download the files (two at a time)

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file which has urls of files to download.

For example:

```
https://url-of/file1.zip
https://url-of/file2.zip
https://url-of/file3.zip
...
```

The command i am currently using to download files is:

```
wget --continue --tries=0 https://url-of/file.zip
```

But now I need a bash script which will read urls from the file and download, two at a time.

The script i came up with so far is:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat file.txt |while read url
do
    wget --continue --tries=0 "$url"
done
```

But it download single file.

How can i edit it so that it download two files at a time.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - use `xargs -P` or GNU `parallel` for this: `xargs -a file.txt -n1 -P 2 wget --continue --tries=0`

Comment: Just for future reference, you don't need `cat` in your loop. Just feed the file directly into the loop: `while IFS= read -r url` // `do` // `wget...` // `done <file.txt`

Comment: @muru I am currently using your solution. I am interested to know how the `gnu parallel` command will look like.

Comment: @muru I am assuming it is something like `cat batch-file.txt | parallel -j2 wget --continue --tries=0 --timeout=60 --waitretry=60 --quiet --show-progress {}`. However, it does not show any output. I would like to see the progress bar for both.

Comment: If it doesn't show any output at all, check if you have `parallel` from `moreutils` (which has a different syntax than GNU parallel). The example command I gave for `xargs` should work with GNU xargs. Progress bar for both simultaneously is going to be tricky, because you will get overlapping output. What I'd suggest is doing something like: `xargs -a file.txt -n1 -P 2 --process-slot-var INDEX sh -c 'exec wget --continue --tries=0 "$1" 2>>"wget-$INDEX.log" _` and running `tail -f wget-1.log`, `tail -f wget-2.log` in separate terminals.

Comment: The command that i came up with is `cat batch-file.txt | parallel -j2 --lb wget --continue --tries=0 --timeout=60 --waitretry=60 --quiet --show-progress {}`. After `--lb` now it shows output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put multiple read commands in the while loop. For "two at a time", but them both in the background and then wait for them to complete

```bash
while read -r first && read -r second; do
    wget "$first" &
    wget "$second" &
    wait
done < input.file
```

But @muru's comment is preferable.